# how to do port forwarding with php using a normal hosting service

Tags: php, networking, port, portforwarding, forwarding

I think so many people have previously searched for such question ..
Is it possible to do port forwarding with some PHP script on a normal hosting service ?
for example , use a local program to exchange data with server with normal GET / POST requests to a specific PHP page
and maybe a program on the other side (client) also a simple program to use this port forwarding method to send requests to the local server

or is there any idea similar to this ?

Comment: Port forwarding is a network concept which cannot be performed by PHP. But I really don't think this is the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: you can't do it using PHP but `nginx` or `apache` may help you